# Copy / migrate users from Firebase Auth to Google Identity Platform

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-identity

I've been using Firebase auth to handle sign-in / sign up in my application (react/express js) which contains now +2000 users.

We are going to migrate to use a new project in Identity Platform (to benefit from SAML etc) which uses the same SDK of the firebase. So now we have 2 separate projects, is there a way to copy all users in that Identity Platform new project? or can I combine them and use them simultaneously?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @xgeek95, I have a similar question, did you find any answer to yours?
What happend to your firebase users, were they still able to authenticate like nothing changed? and how about new users who authenticate since you activated identity platform, ae they moved out from firebase?

I couldn't find any answers to those online, your help would be very much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

from the docs:
https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/migrate-users-between-projects-tenants

```html
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

var sourceApp = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert('source-project-service-account.json'),
}, 'source-app');

var targetApp = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert('target-project-service-account.json'),
}, 'target-app');

var authFrom = sourceApp.auth();
var authTo = targetApp.auth();

function migrateUsers(userImportOptions, nextPageToken) {
 var pageToken;
 authFrom.listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
   .then(function(listUsersResult) {
    var users = [];
    listUsersResult.users.forEach(function(user) {
      var modifiedUser = user.toJSON();
      // Convert to bytes.
      if (user.passwordHash) {
       modifiedUser.passwordHash = Buffer.from(user.passwordHash, 'base64');
       modifiedUser.passwordSalt = Buffer.from(user.passwordSalt, 'base64');
      }
      // Delete tenant ID if available. This will be set automatically.
      delete modifiedUser.tenantId;
      users.push(modifiedUser);
    });
    // Save next page token.
    pageToken = listUsersResult.pageToken;
    // Upload current chunk.
    return authTo.importUsers(users, userImportOptions);
   })
   .then(function(results) {
    results.errors.forEach(function(indexedError) {
       console.log('Error importing user ' + indexedError.index);
     });
     // Continue if there is another page.
     if (pageToken) {
         migrateUsers(userImportOptions, pageToken);
     }
   })
   .catch(function(error) {
     console.log('Error importing users:', error);
   });
}
var userImportOptions = {
 hash: {
   algorithm: 'SCRYPT',
   // The following parameters can be obtained from the "Users" page in the
   // Cloud Console. The key must be a byte buffer.
   key: Buffer.from('base64-secret', 'base64'),
   saltSeparator: Buffer.from('base64SaltSeparator', 'base64'),
   rounds: 8,
   memoryCost: 14
 }
};

migrateUsers(userImportOptions);
```